# How to remove empty lists from a list in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-pub

I have an issue in my Dart Programme. Here is a list of emojis:

```
[[, , ], [], [, , ], [], [], []] //List
```

Inside the list there are multiple lists (as you can see). I want to remove empty lists `[]`. Also I want to Join [, , , , , ] into a single list.

Comment: check `List.where` and `List.fold` / `List.reduce` methods - more: [Iterable collections](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables)

Comment: Not Working. Can You Explain me Better

Comment: `List<List> l = [[1,2,3], [], [4,5], [], [6]]; var merged = l.reduce((a, b) => a + b); print(merged);`

Comment: `var flattened = [for (var sublist in list) ...sublist];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Full Solution**:

```
var data = [['', '', ''], [], ['', '', ''], [], [], []];

void main() {
  var newData = data.expand((x) => x).toList();
  print(newData);
}
```

Here, `newData` is your final answer as: `[, , , , , ]`.

Comment: This Helped a Lot, But can You Explain me Yatinj Why "x" is used in this List

Comment: Here, `x` refers to an individual element of your `data` list. You can see [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/expand.html).

Comment: Like, "i" we have in loops?

Comment: You can not say `i`, because `i` refers to an index basically in the loop. Here `x` shows that individual element. For your given case, in the first iteration, the value of `x` will be `['', '', '']`, in the second iteration, the value of `x` will be `[]`, for third `['', '', '']` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line:

```
yourData.expand((x) => x).toList();
```

Comment: Love you, Thanks a Lot, this helped me So much